# How to concatenate date column in excel with another column keeping original date intact?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns in excel:

InsertDate, FeedbackId

I want to concatenate  these two columns by separating them with a comma. I have written this formula:-=concatenate(B212,"---", C212) but the problem is it is converting the date to some integer i.e.

InsertDate=05-Jun-2017 and FeedbackId=1,

The output is "42891,1" which I want to be "05-Jun-2017,1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following use TEXT to convert to a string for concatenation

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(InsertDate,"dd-mmm-yyyy"),",",FeedbackID)
```